# how to run a jupyter notebook macro in a for loop

Tags: for-loop, macros, jupyter-notebook

I defined a macro `inc` in Jupyter Notebook.  I can run a macro from another cell.  However, the macro cannot be run in the for loop.

[1]

```
x = 0
```

[2]

```
x += 1
```

[3]

```
%macro inc 2
```

[4]

```
inc
```

[5]

```
x
```

outputs 2

[6]

```
for _ in range(10): inc
```

[7]

```
x
```

still outputs 2.

Comment: I added another solution that should work for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best I came up with right now is using `run_cell` method

First you need to grab current interactive Ipython shell with `get_ipython`

#### Full example

```
ip = get_ipython()
for _ in range(5): ips.run_cell('inc')
```

This is not a solution that fully satisfies me but it maybe someone else will be able to add something better.

---

> **Note:** Solution below works for older `Ipython`

try just running it as a callable:

```
for _ in range(10): inc()
```

### Explanation

Ipython macros are instances of `IPython.core.macro.Macro`

[Documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.macro.html) states that it is just a simple objects storing chunk of history in a variable. And this is true.

```
In [20]: inc.__dict__
Out[20]: {'value': u'x += 1\n'}
```

You can also read:

> Macro is just a callable that executes a string of IPython

Comment: I added ( ) and got `TypeError: 'Macro' object is not callable`